# Why is $H^n(\mathbb{R}P^2;\mathbb{Z}) \otimes H^n(S^1;\mathbb{Z}) \not =0$ in degree $n = 1,2$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, projective-space

> Compute $$H^*(\mathbb{R}P^2\times \mathbb{R}P^2, \mathbb{Z}).$$
> **Hint:** Consider the Mayer-Vietoris sequence of suitable open sets of the form $\mathbb{R}P^2\times U$ and $\mathbb{R}P^2\times V$ where
> $U$ is a small disk in $\mathbb{R}P^2$.

So i was trying to understand the proposed solution to this exercise. But building the Mayer-Vietoris sequence goes wrong since i somehow end up getting $$H^*(\mathbb{R}P^2;\mathbb{Z}) \otimes H^*(S^1;\mathbb{Z}) = 0$$

which is apparently wrong.

---

The solutions begins with:

> Viewing $\mathbb{R}P^2$ as $D^2/{\sim}$ where we identify $p \in S^1 =
>  \partial D^2$ with $−p$, we set $U$ to be a small disk around $0 \in 
>  D^2$ and $V = \mathbb{R}P^2 − \{0\}$. Thus $U$ is contractible and $V$
> deformation retracts onto the subspace $S^1/{\sim}$, which is
> homeomorphic to $S^1$ through a loop joining $p$ and $−p$.
>
> We consider the Mayer-Vietoris sequence of the cover $\mathbb{R}P^2 \times U, \mathbb{R}P^2 \times V$. Note that the intersection is given by $\mathbb{R}P^2 \times (U \cap V )$. As $U$ is
> contractible $\mathbb{R}P^2 \times U$ is homotopy equivalent to $\mathbb{R}P^2$.

That's all fine. But my issue begins now by plugging in the cohomologies into the Mayer-Vietoris sequence which is given by

$$\cdots \to H^1(X;\mathbb{Z}) \to H^1(A;\mathbb{Z})\oplus H^1(B;\mathbb{Z}) \to H^1(A\cap B;\mathbb{Z}) \to H^2(X;\mathbb{Z})\to \cdots$$

Let's ignore the degree $0$ stuff for now.

I know that $$H^*(\mathbb{R}P^2,\mathbb{Z}) = \begin{cases} \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} & * = 2 \\ 0 & \text{else} \end{cases}$$
and clearly $$H^*(S^1,\mathbb{Z}) = \begin{cases} \mathbb{Z} & * = 1 \\ 0 & \text{else} \end{cases}$$

Since $A:= \mathbb{R}P^2 \times U$ is homotopy equivalent to $\mathbb{R}P^2$, we have $$H^*(A;\mathbb{Z}) = H^*(\mathbb{R}P^2\times U;\mathbb{Z}) \cong H^*(\mathbb{R}P^2;\mathbb{Z})$$

$B:= \mathbb{R}P^2 \times V$ is homotopy equivalent to $\mathbb{R}P^2\times S^1$ and since $S^1$ is finitely generated free abelian, by the Künneth formula we get

$$ H^*(\mathbb{R}P^2\times V;\mathbb{Z}) \cong H^*(\mathbb{R}P^2\times S^1;\mathbb{Z}) = H^*(\mathbb{R}P^2;\mathbb{Z}) \otimes H^*(S^1;\mathbb{Z})$$

---

**Here is where i have issues:**

Since $H^n(\mathbb{R}P^2;\mathbb{Z})$ vanishes in degree other than $n=2$ and $H^*(S^1;\mathbb{Z})$ vanishes in degree other than $n=1$, the tensor product $H^*(\mathbb{R}P^2;\mathbb{Z}) \otimes H^*(S^1;\mathbb{Z})$ should give me always $0$, shouldn't it?

Somehow this seems to be wrong but i don't know why.

Comment: the tensor is not computed "degreewise". In general, if we have graded abelian groups $A_*$ and $B_*$, then $(A_* \otimes B_*)_n = \bigoplus_{i+j=n} A_i \otimes B_j$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> $H^n(\mathbb{R}P^2;\mathbb{Z})$ vanishes in degree other than $n=2$ and $H^*(S^1;\mathbb{Z})$ vanishes in degree other than $n=1$

This is only true for *reduced* cohomology.  For unreduced cohomology, both of them have $\mathbb{Z}$ in $H^0$ as well.

In addition, note that $H^*(\mathbb{R}P^2;\mathbb{Z}) \otimes H^*(S^1;\mathbb{Z})$ does *not* mean you are taking the tensor product $H^n(\mathbb{R}P^2;\mathbb{Z}) \otimes H^n(S^1;\mathbb{Z})$ separately in each degree.  Rather, it means you are taking the tensor product of the entire cohomology rings (all degrees together).  This means that the degree $n$ part of the tensor product will be the direct sum of all ways to tensor parts whose degrees add up to $n$, i.e. $\bigoplus_{p+q=n}H^p(\mathbb{R}P^2;\mathbb{Z}) \otimes H^q(S^1;\mathbb{Z})$.  So for instance, the nontrivial $H^2(\mathbb{R}P^2;\mathbb{Z})$ and $H^1(S^1;\mathbb{Z})$ will get tensored together to give something nontrivial in $H^3$.  (Note that this additionally means that even if you don't care about $H^0$ in the end, you still have to take into account the unreduced $H^0$ of each factor, since terms like $H^0\otimes H^n$ and $H^n\otimes H^0$ will appear in the $n$th degree of the tensor product.)

Comment: That's just perfect, thank you so much Eric. Your answer is tremendously helpful.

Comment: One question, let's say i wanted to compute the degree $1$ part of the tensor product, would that translate to $$H^1(X\times Y) = H^1(X)\otimes H^0(Y) \oplus H^0(X) \otimes H^1(Y)$$ is that correct?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: Thank you Eric.

Comment: Sorry, i have to ask again. Let's say i would like to compute $H^1(B)$ from above. For the unreduced cohomology i get 

$$H^1(B) = H^1(\mathbb{R}P^2)\otimes H^1(S^1) = H^0(\mathbb{R}P^2)\otimes H^1(S^1)\oplus H^1(\mathbb{R}P^2)\otimes H^0(S^1)$$ resulting in $$H^1(B) = \mathbb{Z}\otimes \mathbb{Z}$$

for the reduced cohomology i get $$\widetilde{H}^1(B) = 0$$ are both results possibly correct? According to the solution, that's wrong somehow. The MV-Sequence is $$\cdots \to H^1(X)\to \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z} \to H^2(X) \to \cdots$$

Comment: The Kunneth theorem (in the form that you are using) applies only to unreduced cohomology, not reduced cohomology.

Comment: Ah, that's good to know. Anyway, is $H^1(B) = \mathbb{Z}\otimes \mathbb{Z}$ still correct? I'm concerned since i can't get to the MV-sequence i mentioned.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.